# Set variable in a rule and have it available in another rule

Tags: makefile

I've the following makefile:

```
.ONESHELL:

SHELL := /bin/bash

build-%:
        @[ $(findstring -, $*) ] && DIR_ENV=$(subst -,/,$*) || DIR_ENV=$*
        @echo ${DIR_ENV}
```

I'm trying to have available the `DIR_ENV` but without no luck. I know that every command executed is executed in its own shell so no sharing of variavbles. However I've added `ONESHELL` directive. But it still doesn't work. What am I'm missing?

Comment: 1) Do you want `DIR_ENV` available in other commands withing that rule, or in other rules? 2) Which version of Make are you using? 3) What happens when you put the `echo` command in the first line (e.g. `DIR_ENV=foo; echo ${DIR_ENV}`)? 4) have you tried doubling the '$' (`echo $${DIR_ENV}`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the fact the string `${DIR_ENV}` is evaluated by make first and the resulting value is a null string.  Use this

```
build-%:
        @[ $(findstring -, $*) ] && DIR_ENV=$(subst -,/,$*) || DIR_ENV=$*
        @echo $${DIR_ENV}
```

Also the Make syntax

```
$(if $(findstring -,$*),$(subst -,/,$*),$*)
```

Does the if/then/else logic in Make, not the shell

Comment: I was thinking over lunch the entire if/then/else can be replaced with a single `@echo '$(subst -,/,$*)'` statement.